# Does'nt Liferay work at different ports?

Tags: liferay, server, portal

I have developed a portal page using Liferay and the port number is 8080. I wanted to test SSO, I decided not to try with the existing one as there might be some problems and I might end up crashing the whole thing. As a result I downloaded a new liferay portal. Iadded it to the eclipse and ran the second server whose port number was changed to 8085. But the webpage displayed when the second server ran was still 8080 and the same page as the first portal. Later I downloaded the enterprise edition and did the same, still 8080: 1st portal. I changed the plugins, no progress. Later, I changed the port number of first one to 8090. The page was not being displayed at all. Why is it like this? I don't get it. Does liferay work with a single port or can't there be  two Liferay portal at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always navigate to exactly the port that you configure - given that the appserver actually serves connections to the port. Common mistakes that I see (assuming you're running tomcat):

- People change `server.xml` to refer `8080` to `8090`, but leave the other ports (`8005` and `8009`) untouched. This means that there are conflicts with two tomcats. If you run both tomcats at the same time, the second one will not start, because another program is already listening to 8005 and/or 8009). You'll need to change all ports to unique values (search server.xml for all declarations of `port=`
- You're relying on the browser to automatically open. Liferay's portal-ext.properties allows to override the page to automatically open - either to being empty or to a specific other URL. Configure browser.launcher.url to your requirements (see below)
- There might be other servers running on either port that you're trying to have tomcat - or any other appserver - listening on.

(Here's the default for `browser.launcher.url`)

```
 # Enter a URL to automatically launch a browser to that URL when the portal
 # has fully initialized. Enter a blank URL to disable this feature.
 #
 browser.launcher.url=http://localhost:8080
```